# swift - Pass generic type to method with more specific extension requirements

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

So the title is a little weirdly worded, but here is the basis of what I am looking to do. I want to make a function that can determine if the generic type given extends from a specific protocol and then pass through the type to the more specific method for processing. This would be using the swift programming language to do so.

Psuedo code of what I want to achieve below:

```
func doStuff<T>(callback: Callback<T>) {
    // Pseudo code of what I want to achieve as I'm not sure the syntax
    // nor if it's even possible
    if T extends Protocol {
        let tExtendsProtocolType = T.Type as Protocol
        mapStuffSpecific<tExtendsProtocolType>(callback: callback)
    } else {
        // Standard Use Case
    }
}

func doStuffSpecific<T: Protocol>(callback: Callback<T> {

}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

```
typealias Callback<T> = (T) -> Void

protocol Protocol {}

struct A {}
struct B: Protocol {}

// I want to be able to use this to do some common set up then call into either doStuff<T> or doStuff<T: Protocol>
func tryDoStuff<T>(callback: Callback<T>) {
    // Do some common setup then call this
    doStuff(callback: callback)
}

func doStuff<T>(callback: Callback<T>) {
    print("doStuff")
}

func doStuff<T: Protocol>(callback: Callback<T>) {
    print("doStuffSpecific")
}

let callbackA: Callback<A> = { _ in } // Just an empty closure
let callbackB: Callback<B> = { _ in }

tryDoStuff(callback: callbackA) // prints doStuff
tryDoStuff(callback: callbackB) // prints doStuffSpecific
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift's overload resolution algorithm already prioritizes the most specific overload available. Here's an example:

```
typealias Callback<T> = (T) -> Void

protocol Protocol {}

struct A {}
struct B: Protocol {}

func doStuff<T>(callback: Callback<T>) {
    print("doStuff")
}

func doStuff<T: Protocol>(callback: Callback<T>) {
    print("doStuffSpecific")
}

let callbackA: Callback<A> = { _ in } // Just an empty closure
let callbackB: Callback<B> = { _ in }


doStuff(callback: callbackA) // prints doStuff
doStuff(callback: callbackB) // prints doStuffSpecific
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. I made a quick addition to your code to better show what i am trying to do. Basically `doStuff<T>` and `doStuff<T: Protocol>` have some common set up. which after the set up is done I then want to call one or the other. Is there a way to achieve this how I have set it up above (vs say making a common `func setUp()` that returns what they both need and proceed). The way the library I'm using is set up is kind of forcing me down this path unless I duplicate all my methods as you have shown above. Any thoughts.